# amix option/command normalize discontinued?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to sum my audio with amix, and not have every input multiplied by 1/n (where n in the number of inputs) prior to summing.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix
Documentation says there is a normalize option to turn off normalization, and a normalize command to do the same.

Running command:

```
ffmpeg -h filter=amix

    Filter amix
  Audio mixing.
    Inputs:
        dynamic (depending on the options)
    Outputs:
       #0: default (audio)
amix AVOptions:
  inputs            <int>        ..F.A... Number of inputs. (from 1 to 1024) (default 2)
  duration          <int>        ..F.A... How to determine the end-of-stream. (from 0 to 2) (default longest)
     longest                      ..F.A... Duration of longest input.
     shortest                     ..F.A... Duration of shortest input.
     first                        ..F.A... Duration of first input.
  dropout_transition <float>      ..F.A... Transition time, in seconds, for volume renormalization when an input stream ends. (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 2)
```

it sadly looks like the option does not exist.

I tried amix=normalize=0 as well as asendcmd=c='0 amix normalize 0' but error messages reported the option/command did not exist, as was shown in the help page.

Here is my ffmpeg version, apt says it's up to date:

```
     ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

How can I sum my audio without this multiplication by 1/n to occur ? Is there another filter than amix ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Distro repositories tend to lag behind. Current latest release is 4.4. Get a static build from http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: @Gyan Ah ok it's not discontinued, it's actually my Ubuntu version that's out of date. Ok nice. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gyan in the comments pointed out my ffmpeg version from the Ubuntu apt package manager was out of date.
Downloading the latest version from ffmpeg.org/download.html will fix the problem.
I'm still a noob regarding Linux stuff... I hope I can somehow declare this ffmpeg version I downloaded from the website in apt because it's always confusing to download many programs and override the package manager, then you forget what you have and where it is. I'll look for a way to do that, package managers are still pretty neat.